# How to Retrieve current ApplicationContext loaded by Multipart Dispatcher Servlet without creating a new one?

Tags: spring, servlets, dispatcher, multipart, applicationcontext

When my application server starts, my `ApplicationContext` is loaded by Multipart Servlet.

I have multiple inbound message listener on some queues. Each message-read from different queue represents a different thread. The messages travel along my application flow and I need to retrieve the current application context (loaded before by multipart) and inject into my singleton class.

Is there a method to achieve this?

PS: I don't have control on dispatcher servlet ... it's a big problem

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> I resolved it. I create a `classfactorybean` on xml that implements `ApplicationContextAware` with relatives methods (particular `setApplicationContext`). This last method is called by callback and retrieve automatically the context loaded by Multipart at server startup and inject the context into my bean (in the bootstrap phase).

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)).